# get one Data/Item from localStorage "local CartItems" in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a localstorage "local CartItems" with this in it:

```
0: {Name: "a", Category: "a", Price: 25.99, Image: "shirt.jpg"}
1: {Name: "b", Category: "b", Price: 25.99, Image: "shirtB.jpg"}
2: {Name: "c", Category: "c", Price: 15.25, Image: "mugA.jpg"}
3: {Name: "d", Category: "d", Price: 10.99, Image: "candleA.jpg"}
```

I can get all of the Items out with this:
cartitem.model.component.ts

```
cartstring!: string;
cartNameString!: string;
cartPrice!:number;


getCart(){

    let carts:cartitem[] = []; 
    if(localStorage.getItem('local CartItems') !=null){
      this.cartstring= JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('local CartItems')as string);
        carts = JSON.parse(this.cartstring);
   }
   return carts;
  // return carts.filter(x => x.productName === Name); -> doesnt work
  }
```

In the html i simply put between the li>:
{{cartstring}}

But the cart looks like hell then:
[{"Name":"a","Category":"a","Price":25.99,"Image":"shirt.jpg"}] for each product.

Thats not how a cart should look D:

**Is there a way to for example only get the Name or Price out of the localstorage "local CartItems"?**

I tried something like this, to sort it with keys:

```
 getCartName(){
    var localStorageArray = new Array();
    if(localStorage.getItem('local CartItems') !=null){
      for(let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
        localStorageArray[i] = localStorage.key(i)+JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i) as string) as string);
      }
    }
    var sortedArray = localStorageArray.sort();
    return sortedArray;
  }
```

but it always returns me that its empty...i just think i didnt get the localstorage.key() function, since when i do console.log(localstorage.key()) it shows me: ƒ key() { [native code] }

Trying my best here, but as a beginner its always so hard!

Comment: Add the output of the getCart

Comment: You mean in ngOnInit() : void {
    this.getCart()} ? that doesnt do it either D:

Comment: Your local cart is and array of object

Comment: Remove `JSON.stringify` from your `this.cartString` assignment because it's already receiving a string from `localStorage`. That way your JSON.parse on the next line isn't parsing a double wrapped string.

Comment: Thanks, now it do is showing it to me as an array. Is there a way to print the array out in the html file? atm i can only find it with innerHTML and javascript

Comment: Or actually I just try to replace some of the string outputs this.cartstring.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'"*?<>{}]/g,"") ..but here actually it doesnt work. When i try like this: cartstring = cartstring.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'"*?<>{}]/g,"") ; It works even less

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your output is  [{"Name":"a","Category":"a","Price":25.99,"Image":"shirt.jpg"}], and you need to display the name and price for the user, you can simply

*{{ cartString[0].Name }}, {{ cartString[0].Price }}* which will appear as *a, 25.99*

In Angular 12, this probably will throw an error. But there are some workarounds.
Kindly reply with the result.